# jquery-countdownTimer in online exam site.autosubmit with time elasped,browser close,page refresh and click back

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I used "Reverse countdown to zero from time set to hours and minutes" from http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/ in my site which does online exam .

A student need to appear exam and complete it for a given period of time let's say after n minutes.

1>After n minutes the page must be auto submitted.

2>Before n minutes if the student close the browser or click back or refresh the page then a confirm box should come

i>if yes,then the page must be submitted.But during that duration the countdown must continued.

ii>if exit,then student must proceed the exam for rest of his time duration.

```javascript
var time_in_sec = parseInt(hours*3600, 10) + parseInt(minutes*60, 10);
time_in_sec *= 1000;

$(function(){
    $('#hm_timer').countdowntimer({
        hours : hours,
        minutes :minutes,
        size : "lg"
    });
    alert("Don't Click Back or Close window before completion.");//Alert before start exam
});


    setTimeout(
        function(){
            alert("You reached the time limit.");
            document.getElementById("appear_exam").submit();///form id
        },time_in_sec);


  jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.returnValue = "confirm('Do you really want to exit this exam?')";
     return event.returnValue;
});
```

Please help
How do I check whether all these actions(close browser,page refresh or clicking back) before n minutes has taken place and how can I continue the countdown during such actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used php script to set the time in the session instead of jquery timer and my problem has solved.

In the Controller:

```
            if(!empty($test_assigned)){
            $test_detail = $this->Test->findById($test_id);
            $total_time = explode(':',$test_detail['Test']['total_time']);
            $data_arr = $test_detail['Test'];
            $data_arr['htime'] = $total_time[0];
            $data_arr['mtime'] = $total_time[1];
            $test_detail = array('Test'=>$data_arr);
            $this->set('test_detail',$test_detail);
            $this->set('list',$this->Question->getQuestionsForTest($test_id));

            if($this->Session->read('timer_count') != '') {
                // session variable_exists, use that
                $targetDate = $this->Session->read('timer_count');
            } else {//comes here with 1st page load then for each next refresh goes to if
                // No session variable, red from mysql
                $hours = $data_arr['htime']; // Enter hours
                $minutes = $data_arr['mtime']; // Enter minutes
                $seconds = 0; // Enter seconds
                //$time_limit = ($hours * 60 * 60) + ($minutes * 60) + $seconds + 1; // Convert total time into seconds
                $seconds += 1; 
                $targetDate = strtotime("$hours hours $minutes minutes $seconds seconds"); 

                $this->Session->write('timer_count' , $targetDate);
                $this->Session->write('test_id' , $test_id);
            }

            $actualDate = time();
            $secondsDiff = $targetDate - $actualDate;
            $remainingDay     = floor($secondsDiff/60/60/24);
            $remainingHour    = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24))/60/60);
            $remainingMinutes = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24) - ($remainingHour*60*60))/60);
            $remainingSeconds = floor(($secondsDiff-($remainingDay*60*60*24) - ($remainingHour*60*60))-($remainingMinutes*60));
            $dateFormat = "g:i a";
            $actualDateDisplay = date($dateFormat,$actualDate);
            $targetDateDisplay = date($dateFormat,$targetDate);


            $this->set('remainingHour',$remainingHour);
            $this->set('remainingMinutes',$remainingMinutes);
            $this->set('remainingSeconds',$remainingSeconds);
```

In the View:

```
    <?php echo $this->html->css("timer/font/timer.css");?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var hours = <?php echo $remainingHour; ?>  
var minutes = <?php echo $remainingMinutes; ?>  
var seconds = <?php echo $remainingSeconds; ?> 
//alert("  "+hours+" hr "+minutes+" min    "+seconds+" sec");
function setCountDown (){
    seconds--;
    if (seconds < 0){
        minutes--;
        seconds = 59;
    }
    if (minutes < 0){
        hours--;
        minutes = 59;
    }
    if (hours < 0){
        hours = 23;
    }
    var h1 = hours; if(h1 == 0 || h1 < 10){h1 = '0'+h1;}
    var m1 = minutes;if(m1 == 0 || m1 < 10){m1 = '0'+m1;}
    var s1 = seconds;if(s1 == 0 || s1 < 10){s1 = '0'+s1;}
    document.getElementById("htd").innerHTML = h1;
    document.getElementById("mtd").innerHTML = m1;
    document.getElementById("std").innerHTML = s1;
    document.getElementById("time_elasped").value = h1+':'+m1+':'+s1;
    SD=window.setTimeout( "setCountDown()", 1000 );
    if((s1 == '00' || s1 == '0') && (m1 == '00' || m1 == '0') && (h1 == '00' || h1 == '0')){ 
        seconds = "00"; window.clearTimeout(SD);
        alert("You reached the time limit.");
        document.getElementById("appear_exam").submit();
        //window.location = "result.php"
    } 
}
$(function(){
    setCountDown();
});
</script>
<div style="float:left; margin-left:10px; position:fixed; margin-top:-30px;">
<table class="timer-table">
    <tr >
        <td class="timer-td">Hrs</td>
        <td class="timer-td">Mins</td>
        <td class="timer-td">Secs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="htd" class="timer-td1"><?php echo "$remainingHour";?></td>
        <td id="mtd" class="timer-td1"><?php echo "$remainingMinutes";?></td>
        <td id="std" class="timer-td1"><?php echo "$remainingSeconds";?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```